# How to use R package bigrquery to load sample data from google big query

Tags: r, google-bigquery, google-query-language

Currently I'm trying to learn something from bigrquery. I found some help on Hadley's github [repository]: https://github.com/hadley/bigrquery . I follow the instruction exactly (I creat my own project ID and corresponding number) but I still cannot get the sample data from the website.

Here is my code:

```
library(bigrquery)
project <- "237216145162" 
sql <- "SELECT year, month, day, weight_pounds FROM natality LIMIT 5"
data <- query_exec("publicdata", "samples", sql, billing = project)

Waiting for authentication in browser...
```

Then my browser pops up and shows

```
Error: invalid_request

Required parameter is missing: response_type

Learn more
```

When I press `learn more` it goes to a link of using OAuth2.0 to access google APIs which is totally new to me.

Can anyone help me with this? I'm not quite familiar with this and I think this involves  other knowledge.

Much appreciate for the help.

Comment: can you post the URL it generated for you to visit in your browser?

Comment: Do you mean the URL produces the Error message above? (I tried on another laptop during the weekend and it worked just fine. Now when I shift back to this laptop it still doesn't work)

Answer (score 1):

From the sound of things, you've got some sort of issue with either running the local webserver or hitting the auth URL directly on your machine. I'd be interested to know what OS/browser/etc.

We can debug that, but there's an easy workaround to get you unblocked -- first, from your R session, run

```
options("httr_oob_default" = TRUE)
```

and try your command again. This will ask `httr` to use a slightly different way to set up the auth dance (in particular with copy-pasting the URL and a response code) that should get you up and running.